# Laravel adding custom attribute to where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `mutator` that calculate the product existing quantity by:

***summing the product credit and minus it from the sold credit***.

```
public function getReportTotalQuantityAttribute() {
    // GET IMPORT INVOICE SUM
    $import_invoices_sum = $this -> credits -> sum('quantity');

    // GET EXPORT INVOICE SUM
    $export_invoices_sum = $this -> sold -> sum('quantity');

    // CALCULATE THE SUM
    return $import_invoices_sum - $export_invoices_sum;
}
```

This `mutator` works fine and return the actually product quantity as `report_total_quantity` attribute whenever I call the model.

## What I am trying to do:

I am trying to get the product `where('report_total_quantity', '>', 0)`.

## What I have tried:

```
$condition_queries = Product::withCreditsAndWarehouses() -> where('report_total_quantity', '>', 0);
```

But I am getting error say `Unknown column 'report_total_quantity'`. And this is logical since I don't have this column but I append it using `$append` and `mutator`.

## What I searched and found:

I have found something called `filters` but I don't think it is good solution since I am using `paginate(10)` and like that I will return `10` values and filter them.

Also I have many other conditions and filter is not working good for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `WHERE` with attribute create by `mutator` You must first create `Collection` then use `Where` statement.

```
 $condition_queries = Product::withCreditsAndWarehouses()->get()->where('report_total_quantity', '>', 0);
```

But after `->get()` you can not use `paginate`. Instead you must use `Collection` paginate method `forPage`. [Check this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forpage)

Comment: That worked but is that a good solution? I mean does it have side-effects?

Comment: If I have product with name **test 2 and report_total_quantity=0** and another product with name **test2 and report_total_quantity>0** after adding your solution it does not return the **test2** product because it get cancelled using the `where clause`

Comment: @Danny. I do not understand what you mean. if you want filter product with report_total_quantity > 0 this code work. you can filter product before `->get()` and after that use `where('report_total_quantity', '>', 0)`